# How to find the three closest distinct units for each of my sites using SQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I am not entirely sure how to word this in the correct way to properly express what it is I am looking for. But here it goes. I want to locate the three closest distinct units for each of my sites. I have my measured distances as `total_mile`, the starting locations are `from_site_`, and the end locations are `to_unitcod`. However, there are sometimes multiple end locations associated with the same `to_unitcod` that are within the top three shortest distances, where I need three different units for each site.

The code below is the closest I have gotten so far. What could I add to this that will make it select three different/distinct `to_unitcod` for each `from_site_`? Right now it is pulling the three shortest measured distances between each site and unit, which is good, but I would like it to pull the three shortest distances from three different units (`to_unitcod`).

```
    SELECT *
    FROM
        (
        SELECT nearrank, total_mile, from_site_, to_poiname, to_unitcod, to_unitnam,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY from_site_ ORDER BY total_mile ASC) rn
        FROM public.mytable
        ) X
    WHERE rn<=3
    ORDER BY from_site_;
```

Below is a screen shot of the resulting table from the above code if that helps illustrate the problem at all. So for example, the records for the Yukon Weapons Range have one FAIR and two DENA unit codes - where that second DENA needs to be the next closest `to_unitcod`.

[image]

Comment: Do you have geometry column? then you can use nearest neighbour https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html

Comment: You don't hsow a single geometry column in this query, you have a bigint, double, varchar, varchar, varchar, bigint? Am I missing something? If this isn't a GIS problem, it should be on [dba.se]

Answer (score 0):

`to_poiname` is not unique so we need to remove that from the query.

Given that `to_unitcod` is what is being treated as distinct, we can run the following which will get the minimum distance (`min_dist`) for each `from_site_` and `to_unitcod` pair.

This will return the `from_site_`, `to_unitcod`, `min_dist`, `to_unitnam` and `rn`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT from_site_, to_unitcod, MIN(total_mile) min_dist, to_unitnam,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY from_site_ ORDER BY MIN(total_mile)) rn
    FROM public.mytable
    GROUP BY from_site_, to_unitcod,  to_unitnam
    ORDER BY from_site_, MIN(total_mile)
    ) X
WHERE rn<=3
ORDER BY from_site_;
```

The result will be:
[image: Simple Results]

---

If we also do need to see the `to_poiname` and other fields we can do an outer selection on this table as follows:

```
SELECT a.*, X.rn
FROM
public.mytablea,
    (
    SELECT from_site_, to_unitcod, MIN(total_mile) min_dist, to_unitnam,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY from_site_ ORDER BY MIN(total_mile)) rn
    FROM public.mytable
    GROUP BY from_site_, to_unitcod, to_unitnam
    ORDER BY from_site_, MIN(total_mile)
    ) X
WHERE rn<=3 AND (a.from_site_ = X.from_site_ AND a.to_unitcod = X.to_unitcod AND a.total_mile = X.min_dist)
ORDER BY from_site_;
```

The result of this will be:
[image]

*NOTE: I am using a subset of the data so some of the `from_site_` locations only have 2 distinct nearest units, also I didn't populate my `to_unitnam` field*